# Scrap telegram limit 10 000 members

Tags: python, telegram

Good morning,

I am new to the field, I downloaded on git hut a telegram scrapper that works syr pithon. However, I can only scrape a maximum of 10,000 members per group. Here is the source code. Can you tell me if it is possible to modify it to be able to scrap all the members of a group? Thanks for your help

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import os, sys
import configparser
import csv
import time

re="\033[1;31m"
gr="\033[1;32m"
cy="\033[1;36m"

def banner():
    print(f"""
{re}╔╦╗{cy}┌─┐┬  ┌─┐{re}╔═╗  ╔═╗{cy}┌─┐┬─┐┌─┐┌─┐┌─┐┬─┐
{re} ║ {cy}├┤ │  ├┤ {re}║ ╦  ╚═╗{cy}│  ├┬┘├─┤├─┘├┤ ├┬┘
{re} ╩ {cy}└─┘┴─┘└─┘{re}╚═╝  ╚═╝{cy}└─┘┴└─┴ ┴┴  └─┘┴└─
            version : 3.1
youtube.com/channel/UCnknCgg_3pVXS27ThLpw3xQ
        """)

cpass = configparser.RawConfigParser()
cpass.read('config.data')

try:
    api_id = cpass['cred']['id']
    api_hash = cpass['cred']['hash']
    phone = cpass['cred']['phone']
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
except KeyError:
    os.system('clear')
    banner()
    print(re+"[!] run python3 setup.py first !!\n")
    sys.exit(1)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    os.system('clear')
    banner()
    client.sign_in(phone, input(gr+'[+] Enter the code: '+re))
 
os.system('clear')
banner()
chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups=[]
 
result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
         ))
chats.extend(result.chats)
 
for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue
 
print(gr+'[+] Choose a group to scrape members :'+re)
i=0
for g in groups:
    print(gr+'['+cy+str(i)+gr+']'+cy+' - '+ g.title)
    i+=1
 
print('')
g_index = input(gr+"[+] Enter a Number : "+re)
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]
 
print(gr+'[+] Fetching Members...')
time.sleep(1)
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)
 
print(gr+'[+] Saving In file...')
time.sleep(1)
with open("members.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id'])
    for user in all_participants:
        if user.username:
            username= user.username
        else:
            username= ""
        if user.first_name:
            first_name= user.first_name
        else:
            first_name= ""
        if user.last_name:
            last_name= user.last_name
        else:
            last_name= ""
        name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
        writer.writerow([username,user.id,user.access_hash,name,target_group.title, target_group.id])      
print(gr+'[+] Members scraped successfully.')
```